# Property/Private or both

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone explain me when should i use Property, Private or both? When i create class what is good practice choose between them. I always see in many examples people used to do it diffrent way.

**Some of them doing like this:**

```
Private _name as string
Private _age as Integer
```

**Other people does:**

```
Property Name as string
Property Age as Integer
```

**and other people:**

```
Private _name As String
Private _age As Integer

Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _name 
        End Get

        Set
            _name = value
        End Set
End Property

Public Property age() As Integer
        Get
            Return _age 
        End Get

        Set
            _age = value
        End Set
End Property
```

in this case what is a sense to use private as Property already hiding private variable so in this case we could call it: _name and _age without specifying it as here.

Comment: Depends on the data and how it will be used.  But they are not mutually exclusive - you could have a `Private Property`.  Auto Implemented props will elide the Get Set boiler plate code though

Comment: See [Differences Between Properties and Variables in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk5e8eth.aspx).

Comment: Actually, #1 is just some private vars in the class.  #2 is the Auto Implement form which comes with free hidden `_name` and `_age` backing fields.  #3 is the older long form with Getters, Setters and backing fields. 2 and 3 are functionally the same just old school vs modern, more productive version

Comment: @Plutonix ok but generally when creating class i see people that times to use automatic properties instead of Private. When i create such property should i use convention Property Name as String or Property _name as String? Which one is "better"?

Comment: Take a cue from the zillions of classes you are exposed to via the Net Framework:  You never see public props names `_name`.  MSDN has articles on naming conventions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use fields (variables) when you want to only store value in memory. You use properties when you want to do more, for example validating it. Property is basically two methods for getting value (Get) and setting value (Set).